# Atomikos Transaction Manager without Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to configure Atomikos Transaction without using spring.First i am trying to set up the EntityManagerFactory without using spring the following is code i have tried

```
private static AtomikosDataSourceBean prepareDataSource(){
        AtomikosDataSourceBean atomikosDataSourceBean = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        atomikosDataSourceBean.setUniqueResourceName("demo");
        atomikosDataSourceBean.setXaDataSourceClassName("oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", "demo");
        properties.setProperty("password", "demo");
        properties.setProperty("URL", "dbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe");
        atomikosDataSourceBean.setXaProperties(properties);
        return atomikosDataSourceBean;
    }


    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(prepareDataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("demo");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform", "com.demo.AtomikosJtaPlatform");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return  (EntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory;

    }
```

The above code is returning me an classcastexception.How can i get the same entitymanagerfactory without using spring

Comment: What is "LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" ? You said without Spring ...

Comment: Yes.My trial was wrong.I need to set up theENtityManager without spring.Please ignore above code

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to the official documentation of Atomikos, which actually contains an example for those who opt for not using Spring:

[Atomikos without Spring](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/HibernateIntegration#Without_Spring)